# Точки внутри скобок

Tags: пунктуация

Как оформлять пунктуационно конструкцию в скобках, которая сама содержит точки?

Вымышленный пример.

*Я хочу задать вопрос по поводу поводу NN. (Я помню, мы прошлый раз о
нем уже говорили, но сейчас я о другом. Меня интересует мнение о его
вчерашнем выступлении.) Если не против, давай встретимся там-то и
тогда-то.*

Допустимо ли такое оформление? особенно интересуют точки перед обеими скобками. На месте ли они стоят?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы написали правильно. 
Правило,  конечно, лучше изложено у Лопатина.

> § 99. Вставная конструкция, будучи самостоятельным предложением или
>   частью текста (ряд предложений), относящаяся к абзацу (текст вставки
>   после открывающей скобки начинается с прописной буквы), выделяется
>   скобками. Перед скобкой, открывающей вставку, ставится необходимый по
>   условиям контекста знак конца предложения.

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=128#pp128

(Sibylla дает эту же ссылку, но текст - якобы из Розенталя, причем я такого не нашел даже у него).

> Точка это тоже "знак обозначающий"? В кавычках она не ставится при 
>   аналогичной формулировке

У Лопатина про обозначающий знак ничего не говорится, просто и ясно: "требуемый по контексту знак конца предложения". И про условие "относящийся к абзацу" тоже понятнее. Это не замечание ко всему абзацу, это некий "абзац", то есть семантически законченная мысль, весь помещенный в скобки). Сомнений быть не должно.

А вот аналогия ваша (если я её правильно понял) надумана. Точка "теряется" внутри кавычек, если идет перед закрывающей кавычкой. Перед кавычкой точка сохраняется. Так что отличие только в том, что внутри скобок точка сохраняется, а внутри кавычек - нет. Все остальное действительно построено на сходной логике. Хотя случаи это, конечно, совершенно разные.

Comment: ясно, спасибо..

Answer (score 4):

Да, всё верно.

ПАС под ред. Лопатина: [Знаки препинания при вставках](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=128#pp128)

Вставная конструкция, будучи самостоятельным предложением или частью текста (ряд предложений), относящаяся к абзацу (текст вставки после открывающей скобки начинается **с прописной буквы**), выделяется скобками. Перед скобкой, открывающей вставку, ставится необходимый по условиям контекста **знак конца предложения**. Перед закрывающей скобкой ставится **знак, фиксирующий конец вставного предложения**: ...Так будет дальновиднее... (У Маслова клокотало в горле, хотя говорит он тихо и даже вяло.) Ничего не изменилось, Екатерина Дмитриевна!...

Comment: У вас многоточие перед открывающей скобкой. Точка это тоже "знак обозначающий"? В кавычках она не ставится при аналогичной формулировке.

Comment: Многоточие, как и точка, - это знак конца предложения. Правило я понимаю так: если вставка является отдельным предложением, то она совершенно самостоятельна, ее можно изъять из предложения, и при этом ничего не изменится. И сама вставка имеет конечный знак (точку или другие знаки).

Comment: Не понял ответа. Но мне уже ответили, спасибо.